# Install apk onto Glass

Tags: eclipse, apk, adb, aero-glass

I have been trying to install a apk file onto my Google Glass (Glass Hunt to be specific) but I have not been able to. I am on a mac and so far I have used Terminal to navigate to platform tools or something like that but then anytime I try to do a command like

`adb install <glass hunt's location>`

It doesn't work. Any ideas? In short I just want to load a apk onto my Glass. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face such problem, try to copy the .app file to the memory card of the device and then install it manually as we install any software on MAC or Windows.

Here is a link, hope that it will give you the answer.

http://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm not trying to put it onto a phone, I already have Glass which does not have a sd card. Sorry about the very late comment, I haven't been on for a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us what error you are seeing? One possible reason could be use of an OLDER SDK or SDK mismatch.
1. Make sure your minimumsdk and targetsdk on your manifest file matches the glass sdk verison. If you have XE12 firmware, either upgrade your firmware version or change your minimumreqiredsdk version to 14.